# Azure DevOps MSBuild Rename File During Build

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I've a file named _app_offline.htm that I'm renaming to app_offline.htm using MSBuild.  This is an older style asp.net website so MSBuild is using website.publishproj:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="RenameAppOffline">
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <RenameFile Include="_app_offline.htm" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(_WebPublishTargetsPath)\Web\Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets" />

  <Target Name="RenameAppOffline">
    <Message Text="Rename: @(RenameFile) -> @(RenameFile -> Replace('_app_offline', 'app_offline'))" Importance="High" />
    <Move SourceFiles="@(RenameFile)" DestinationFiles="@(RenameFile -> Replace('_app_offline', 'app_offline'))" />
  </Target>
  
</Project>
```

The command is:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

In the build log I can see:

Moving file from "_app_offline.htm" to "app_offline.htm".

When I download the artifact, _app_offline.htm is not present, however app_offline.htm is also not present and not deployed.

My question is why is app_offline.htm missing and how can I add it to the artifact?

EDIT 2020-06-29:

I updated RenameAppOffline as follows:

```
<Target Name="RenameAppOffline" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Message Text="Rename: @(RenameFile) -> @(RenameFile -> Replace('_', ''))" Importance="High" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RenameFile)" DestinationFiles="@(RenameFile -> Replace('_', $(_PackageTempDir)\))" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

This fixed my issue

Comment: if you publish locally is it exist?

Comment: How's the result if you publish locally from MSBuild command line? Could you share entire build log in DevOps?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, no it didn't exist locally.  My edit resolved the issue - thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, my edit resolved the issue - thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From various other StackOverflow questions, I was able to piece together the following solution:

```
<Target Name="RenameAppOffline" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Message Text="Rename: @(RenameFile) -> @(RenameFile -> Replace('_', ''))" Importance="High" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RenameFile)" DestinationFiles="@(RenameFile -> Replace('_', $(_PackageTempDir)\))" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

One of the secondary challenges was knowing what environment variables were available - adding the following to the MSBuild command provided all of the information I needed:

```
-v:diag
```